# How to change the constant value in Debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, rad

Can anyone advise how to change the given below expression values.

```
if(StringUtils.equals("Y",dao.getUserStatus("1010")){
          //Conditional true statement
}else{
      //False Statements
}
```

I would like to change "Y" to "N or dao.getUserStatus("1010") return "N" . Objective is make it Condition false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't

Extract a variable like this:

```
String userStatus = dao.getUserStatus("1010");
if (StringUtils.equals("Y", userStatus)) { // Breakpoint here
    // Conditional true statement
} else {
    // False Statements
}
```

and change its value.

---

Another possible solution is to step into `StringUtils#equals` and change the result (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

As @RC mentions, the easy and recommended way is to extract the value in its own variable and then change it. This way you will change the value for this context only.

Now, if you want to make a permanent change in that value, then you can use the watch view, expand the node of your "dao" object and set the "userStatus" to the value you want, you can right click on userStatus and select Set value (the labels might differ as I don't exactly remember them).

Hope this helps.